# Swift 4 Taping on a Annotation

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on my app However, app works fine, but once all the pins `Annotations` are displayed on the map, although the information does show when tapping on the pin, I would like to be able to get the coordinates from the pin `Annotation` and set it to a variable.

Here is my Code

Hope some one can add some code so I can get the data I need.

Thank you.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class mapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate {

var textLat = ""
var textLong = ""
var lat = ""
var long = ""
var ItemSelected = ""
var menuShowing = false
@IBOutlet weak var aboutButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: Any) {
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


// Side Bar Action
@IBAction func sideMenuButton(_ sender: Any) {
    // When Victoria button is selected, Stop updating user location on the map, then go to Functions
    label.isHidden = false
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    sideMenu()
}
@IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

// When nsw Button selected hide side bar and go to Victoria Function also Remove all annotations
@IBAction func nsw(_ sender: Any) {
    let annotations = self.mapView.annotations
    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
    nsw()
    sideMenu()
    }
    // When Victoria Button selected hide side bar and go to Victoria Function also Remove all annotations
    @IBAction func victoria(_ sender: Any) {
    let annotations = self.mapView.annotations
    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
    victoria()
    sideMenu()
    }



    // Map Style Select
    @IBAction func mapSelect(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex){
    case 0:
        mapView.mapType = .standard
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = .hybrid
    default:
        mapView.mapType = .satellite
    }
    }
//Map
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func refreshLocation(_ sender: Any) {
 manager.startUpdatingLocation()
  label.isHidden = true
}
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
let manager = CLLocationManager()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let location = locations[0]

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.80, 0.80)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let locations:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    lat = String(locations.latitude)
    long = String(locations.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    textLat = lat
    textLong = long
   self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true


}





override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Make About Button have corner Radius.
    aboutButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    aboutButton.clipsToBounds = true

    // Change colour of Status Bar
    let statusBarView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame)
    let statusBarColor = UIColor(red: 89/255, green: 89/255, blue: 89/255, alpha: 1)

    statusBarView.backgroundColor = statusBarColor
    view.addSubview(statusBarView)

    manager.delegate = self

    //manager.delegate = self as? CLLocationManagerDelegate
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    // Tracking Label radius
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    label.layer.masksToBounds = true
    // Make Shadow on Side Menu
    menuView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    menuView.layer.shadowRadius = 6



    // Get Data for Map Locations

    }
    func victoria(){
        let points = [
            ["title": "Byrners Motorcycles","Add": "4 Klauer St Seaford Ph 03 9786 9000","latitude":-38.119635, "longitude":145.145476],
            ["title": "AJ's Motorcycles","Add":" 4 Purcell St Shepparton Ph 03 5822 2466","latitude": -36.383757, "longitude": 145.407105],
            ["title": "All West & All Tech Motorcycles","Add":" 3, 14 Harrison Crt Melton Ph 03 9743 0732","latitude": -37.694081, "longitude": 144.599081],
            ["title": "Bairnsdale Motorcycles","Add":" 32 Gordon St, Bairnsdale Ph 03 5152 4337","latitude": -37.834698, "longitude": 147.606052],
            ["title": "Baron Engine Development","Add":" 5/13-15 Kevlar Cl, Braeside  Ph 03 9580 3905","latitude": -37.992994, "longitude": 145.117296],
            ["title": "Barry Francis Motorcycles","Add":"52 Lonsdale St, Hamilton  Ph 03 5572 1899","latitude": -37.742639, "longitude": 142.020682],
            ["title": "Bendigo Yamaha","Add":"22 Bridge St, Bendigo  Ph 03 5442 2595","latitude": -36.753625, "longitude": 144.283283],
            ["title": "Bike Edge","Add":"4/1A Moorefield Park Dr, West Wodonga  Ph 02 6056 9507","latitude": -36.111049, "longitude": 146.862745],
            ["title": "Bikes Plus","Add":"87 Matthews Ave, Airport West  Ph 03 9041 4823","latitude": -37.715424, "longitude": 144.891517],
            ["title": "Brighton Bikes & Bits","Add":"817 Nepean Hwy, Bentleigh  Ph 03 9557 4700","latitude": -37.924175, "longitude": 145.026193],
            ["title": "Doyle & Shields Motorcycles","Add":"74 Macleod St, Bairnsdale  Ph 03 5152 4687","latitude": -37.827222, "longitude": 147.631652],
            ["title": "Dynamite Cycles","Add":"304 Warrenheip St, Buninyong  Ph 0402 181 943","latitude": -37.647063, "longitude": 143.885050],
            ["title": "Elliott Brothers","Add":"43-47 Wattle St, Bendigo  Ph 03 5443 5555","latitude": -36.762499, "longitude": 144.273866],
            ["title": "Halsall Honda","Add":"7 Benalla Rd, Shepparton Ph 03 5821 2459","latitude": -36.383096, "longitude": 145.413622],
            ["title": "Hampton Cycles","Add":"353 Hampton St, Hampton Ph 03 9521 8700","latitude": -37.937332, "longitude": 145.002532],
            ["title": "Hoffmann Motorcycles","Add":"1/2055 Frankston - Flinders Rd, Hastings Ph 03 5979 7687","latitude": -38.304378, "longitude": 145.183662],
            ["title": "Krooztune","Add":"1/62 Wadhurst Dr, Boronia Ph 03 9801 2122","latitude": -37.867251, "longitude": 145.254225],
            ["title": "Madbiker","Add":"2/477 Dorset Rd, Bayswater Ph 03 9729 0000","latitude": -37.834606, "longitude": 145.287104],
            ["title": "Mansfield Marine & Motorcycles","Add":"6 Ogilvies Rd, Mansfield Ph 03 5779 1105","latitude": -37.077344, "longitude": 146.094478],
            ["title": "Mark 1 Motorcycles","Add":"1/3 Lathams Rd, Carrum Downs Ph 03 9775 1299","latitude": -38.099263, "longitude": 145.170815],
            ["title": "Mick Hone Motorcycles","Add":"715 Whitehorse Rd, Mont Albert Ph 03 9890 0304","latitude": -37.815780, "longitude": 145.105911],
            ["title": "Mornington Motorcycles","Add":"185 Mornington-Tyabb Rd, Mornington Ph 03 5976 3800","latitude": -38.237964, "longitude": 145.063299],
            ["title": "Moto G.C","Add":"258 Settlement Rd, Thomastown  Ph 03 9038 9133","latitude": -37.692772, "longitude": 145.029525],



            ]
    for point in points {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = point["title"] as? String
        annotation.subtitle = point["Add"] as? String
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: point["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: point["longitude"] as! Double)


        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)





        }







        }

    func nsw(){
        mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        let points = [
            ["title": "Chris Weekes MC","Add": "1 Goldsmith St Goulburn Ph 02 4821 4911","latitude":-34.751492, "longitude":149.723201],
            ["title": "Graeme Moris MC","Add":" 4 Cameron St Broadmedows Ph 02 4957 0674","latitude": -32.923439, "longitude": 151.725813],
            ["title": "Maitland Motorcycles","Add":"339 High St Maitland Ph 02 4933 1998","latitude": -32.734957, "longitude": 151.558577],
            ]
        for point in points {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = point["title"] as? String
            annotation.subtitle = point["Add"] as? String
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: point["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: point["longitude"] as! Double)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)




        }
        }

    // Function for Side Menu
    func sideMenu(){
    // If menu is showing, Hide menu when button pressed
    if (menuShowing) {
        leadingConstraint.constant = -140
    }
        // Else Show it
    else {
        leadingConstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations:{ self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
    menuShowing = !menuShowing
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
    var getCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        getCoord = view.annotation?.coordinate
        print(getCoord) //Use Coordinates as you want in any places
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks